# UIRepresentable from external class... is that possible?

Tags: swiftui

I am dealing with UIRepresentable.

I have a part like

```
struct MyRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var control: MyScrollView
 
    init(_ control: MyScrollView) {
        self.control = control
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // User is currently scrolling
    }
    
    @objc func handleRefresh(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        sender.endRefreshing()
    }
  }
```

The problem is that what must go inside this coordinator is monstrous, a lot of delegate functions.

I am trying to pass this to a separate file, to reduce the clutter on the representable file.

Then I created a new file like this

```
class MyExternalCoordinator:NSObject, MyDelegate {
  // here goes the monstrous code
}
```

and then, inside my UIViewRepresentable class

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
  MyExternalCoordinator()
}
```

I get the message

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'MyExternalCoordinator' to return type 'MyRepresentable.Coordinator'

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make return type aligned, like

```
  func makeCoordinator() -> MyExternalCoordinator {
    MyExternalCoordinator()
  }
```

Comment: argument passed to call that takes no argument

Comment: The fix is obvious, updated. But it is important to your issue - it is types alignment.

Comment: ahhh, brilliant but it is not intuitive. In theory, MyExternalCoordinator should be a subclass of Coordinator, but it is not. It is a subclass of NSObject. Thanks!